# Moq and testing for a specific call to a service with no other calls

Tags: c#, moq

Say I have a reference to a service called `myService`. It has a method called `MyMethod` which takes an int parameter.

Using Moq, I want to test a particular scenario that means `MyMethod` is called once with a specific value (let's say it's `3`) and to also ensure that no other call is made.

If I wrote:

```
myService.Verify(o => o.MyMethod(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
```

Then this would ensure the method was only called once but I do not know if it was called with `3`.

If I wrote:

```
myService.Verify(o => o.MyMethod(3), Times.Once);
```

Then this would ensure the method was only called once with `3` but I do not know if it was called any other times with values other than `3`.

So, if I want to ensure both that it was only called once with a `3` and it was not called any other times then I would need to have two `Verify` calls like this:

```
myService.Verify(o => o.MyMethod(3), Times.Once);  
myService.Verify(o => o.MyMethod(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
```

Is there any Moq convention that allows me to achieve the same thing with just one `Verify` call?

Comment: Create the mock in `Strict` mode and setup the mocked member `myService.Setup(_ => _.MyMethod(3));`. Now the verify for 3 only will work, and if the mocked member is called with anything other than what was setup it will fail

Comment: Just a small addition to Nkosi's comment. If you want to allow not just `3` but lets say 4 as well then you can use `.Setup(_ => _.MyMethod(It.Is<int>(p => p == 3 || p == 4)))`

Comment: I'd argue you are testing for two different situations: whether it is being called only once and whether it is being called with the value 3. I think it makes the test easier to understand if you make 2 calls to `Verify` rather than what @Nkosi is suggesting, which seems a bit too obscure. I wouldn't expect people to have to understand how Moq works to be able to understand what is being tested.

Comment: Review the quick start here for how strict works https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior

Comment: @AsPas I still believe it is one case being tested here. "Verify that only `MyMethod(3)` is being invoked" when exercising the test

Comment: @Nkosi it is one test case, but two different conditions. Personally, I feel like the test is more understandable if you make 2 calls to `Verify` instead of configuring the mock in an "unexpected" way. Specially because you can be more specific regarding fail messages. But this might just be me.

Comment: What is "unexpected" here? You setup the expectation on the mock, and if that expectation is not met, the test fails.

Comment: To count how many times a method is called - use callback to keep track number of calls made (documented here - https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2021/07/two-ways-to-count-the-number-of-times-a-mocked-method-is-called-with-moq/). To ensure no other calls were made - use VerifyNoMethodsCalled documented here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172998/moq-verify-that-no-methods-were-called   .